# Split large excel into multiple excel file using azure function

Tags: c#, azure

I'm able to split excel file in function but when publishing on azure function is giving timeout exception. what to do.how azure durable functions can help here?

This is how i'm doing it:

```
        bookOriginal.LoadFromStream(BlobService.GetFileFromBlob(filename));
        log.LogInformation("File read from Azure Blob");
        Worksheet sheet = bookOriginal.Worksheets[0];
        var totalRow = sheet.Rows.Count();
        int splitRows = 7000;
        int count = totalRow / splitRows;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            CellRange range1;
            Workbook newBook1 = new Workbook();
            newBook1.CreateEmptySheets(1);
            Worksheet newSheet1 = newBook1.Worksheets[0];
            Model localModel = new Model();
            if (i == 1)
            {
                range1 = sheet.Range[2, 1, splitRows, sheet.LastColumn];
            }
            else
            {
                range1 = sheet.Range[(splitRows * (i - 1)) + 1, 1, splitRows * i, sheet.LastColumn];
            }

            newSheet1.Copy(range1, newSheet1.Range[1, 1]);
            
            //bookOriginal.SaveToFile("Research and Development.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
            localModel.workbookObject = newBook1;
            model.Add(localModel);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Ran Completely");
```

Comment: You need to be more precise. Where exactly is the timeout, what enviroments are you using, etc.

Comment: You can read document about how to set timeout in azure function first. https://build5nines.com/azure-functions-extend-execution-timeout-past-5-minutes/

Comment: I'm using visual studio2017 to create azure function and deploying it on azure and also I have mentioned timeout of 10 minutes in host.json file

Answer (score 0):

Yes durable functions can surely help you!
You can take a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp
The first and the second pattern could help you. The Project structure can be:

- a blob triggered function that downloads the source excel, converting it into one object that you can pass as input invoking the orchestrator .
- The orchestrator function Deserializes the input object and groups the rows as you did in your code
- inside a foreach statement you can use the current group of rows as parameter to invoke an activity. You can choose if activities will run in sequence (as pattern 1 awaiting activity) or run in parallel (As pattern 2 using Task.WhenAll)
- The activity function Converts the row group into an excel File and, using blob attribute as output, uploads it into storage

WARNING: durable Functions documentation sayes: Return values are serialized to JSON and persisted to the orchestration history table in Azure Table storage.

So The input model must be serializable as json.